# How do I find a the namespaces and class names in a .dll file?

Tags: class, dll, namespaces

I need to access the namespaes and class names in a .dll file (msado15.dll) to use them in my cpp project.
I have tried to open it with Resource Hacker, but all I could find was a binary file, a string table (without namespaces or class names) and an info file.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: It is a COM server.  Use the [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) to get the embedded type library converted into C++ code.

Comment: Hans is right. you'd better find an example.